# Text decoration working in Chrome, not in Firefox

Tags: css, text, text-decorations

Here is my site: radiotounsi.com 
Chrome displays the text decoration of the posts titles well, but FF doesn't do it correctly (gap between the title and the decoration)
screenshot chrome (good display) http://s21.postimg.org/6dnqt4wqv/chrome.png
screenshot ff http://s8.postimg.org/wywnkb7mt/image.png
Can you please help me to fix it ? thanks in advance

Comment: Please post a snippet reproducing your problem here (or in a fiddle/codepen). Otherwise no other person will be able to understand and reproduce your problem once it's corrected on your site (or if other modifications occur)

Answer (score 0):

The `h2` heading is displayed as inline: changing it to block should help

```
.bl1-title h2 {
     display: blocck; /* @BUGFIX was inline and Fx displayed it with an overflow of text */
}
```

Comment: FelipeAls thank you very match, this worked, I changed it to inline-block for a better display.